# Quicker way to write a dict to a neo4j database using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, neo4j, cypher

I have a dict and a cypher query with placeholders. My code currently works:

```
def set_dict(self, tx, my_dict):
    for i, j in my_dict.items():
        tx.run("MERGE (n:property_1 {i: $i})
        SET n.j = $j; ",
        i=i, j=j)
```

This works, but rather than looping through and executing `tx.run`, is there a more pythonic/faster was of executing a dict as a placeholder in a CQL string?

Answer (score 0):

The APOC function [apoc.map.sortedProperties](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.map/apoc.map.sortedProperties/) creates a (sorted) list of properties, where each property is represented by a list containing a key and its value. That should be helpful for your use case.

For example:

```
def set_dict(self, tx, my_dict):
    tx.run('''    UNWIND apoc.map.sortedProperties($my_dict) AS prop
                  MERGE (n:property_1 {i: prop[0]}) 
                  SET n.j = prop[1]''',
            my_dict=my_dict)
```

Comment: Thank you for that...I received as error message: neo4j.exceptions.CypherSyntaxError: {code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError} {message: Unknown function 'apoc.map.sortedProperties' (line 1, column 8 (offset: 7))
"UNWIND apoc.map.sortedProperties($my_dict) AS prop" ... It seems to complain about the apoc function

Comment: I see that this is related to the installation of APOC...seems quite cumbersome for the moment so I may have to sideline this. Thanks again